How to make a Spacer visible for debugging in SwiftUI
Lets say, in SwiftUI, we have something like:
VStack{
    Text("I am a dynamic object")
    Spacer() // <----- this is what is being modified in the "what I have tried section below
    Text("Me too.")
    Spacer()
    Text("Me three")
    Spacer()
    Text("hi.")
}
        

We don't know how much space these spacers will take until runtime for various reasons.
So that was a specific example, but in general, how can we make a Spacer() (that is, the entire space that is being dynamically assigned to a single specific spacer at runtime) temporarily visible for debugging?
I have tried replacing the Spacer() above with:
ZStack{
    Spacer()
    Color.pink
}

(behaves exactly as .pink alone would have)
and...
Spacer()
    .overlay(.pink)

(does nothing)
and...
Spacer()
    .background(.pink)

(does nothing)
None of these seem to work.

"(behaves exactly as .pink alone would have)" What behavior were you expecting instead? Both Spacer and Color fill all available space, and so should be the same size. Placed in a ZStack, this seems exactly what you want. How does it fail for you?

I don't think a color behaves the same way as a spacer, since the spacers sort of "know about eachother"? and work in coordination taking equal space.  I'm making edits to clarify.

@TrustyTurtle I don't think the Spacers have any additional insight and "know about each other" more than any other views that greedily take space. You can try putting different Colors in between views and see the same behavior, right?

@jnpdx I have verified they dont behave the same way in a playground.  If you replace one of the vstack spacers with a color, it will render the other spacers to zero size.

Agreed; easy to reproduce in a small test app as well. It's an excellent question.

@TrustyTurtle Ah -- I see, if they're mixed, that's true. But if all of the Spacers are changed to Color, the Colors seem to behave the same way (in my tests so far)

It seems that this problem is analogous to UIKit UILayoutGuide, where we can add spacing constraints that have no associated view. See https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/3be455c999bf7ba1b1c581d54d06b21b for UIKit example with UILayoutGuide. Back in the day, we used to do this sort of spacing with clear/invisible “placeholder” views, but it is more efficient to use layout guides (since it’s silly to have the OS render something that is invisible). But without an actual placeholder view, it admittedly makes debugging a little harder. You have to rely upon secondary behaviors to diagnose.

The reason why you didn't see anything when you put a Color in the background is because a vertical spacer has zero width and a horizontal spacer has zero height.
By applying a minimum width and minimum height to the color, you can make it visible. This works for a horizontal spacer as well as a vertical spacer:
Spacer()
    .background {
        Color.yellow
            .frame(minWidth: 10, minHeight: 10)
    }

Keeping it on one line probably makes it easier to copy/paste and also to comment out:
VStack{
    Text("I am a dynamic object")
    Spacer()
        .background { Color.yellow.frame(minWidth: 10, minHeight: 10) }
    Text("Me too.")
    Spacer()
    Text("Me three")
    Spacer()
    Text("hi.")
}


Technically, you only need to use minHeight for a horizontal spacer and minWidth for a vertical spacer. Then again, it can be useful to know that a spacer is present, even when it is not performing any spacing. If the parent HStack or parent VStack has non-zero spacing then the presence of the Spacer will mean there are more spacing-gaps between the items in the stack.

You can give the background a fixed width if it’s within a VStack and a fixed height if it’s in a HStack. This way, you can add a background to it and make it visible.
VStack {
    Text("I am a dynamic object")
    Spacer()
        .background(Color.cyan.frame(width: 2))
    Text("Me too.")
    Spacer()
    Text("Me three")
    Spacer()
    Text("hi.")
}

or
HStack {
    Text("I am a dynamic object")
    Spacer()
        .background(Color.cyan.frame(height: 2))
    Text("I am a dynamic object")
}

if you're on iOS 17 or higher you can use .containerRelativeFrame to fill up the whole spacer.
VStack {
    Text("I am a dynamic object")
    Spacer()
        .background(Color.cyan.containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal))
}


Instead of only downvoting please provide more information about why this is not working for you.

I appreciate your effort, it's not personal.  It partly my fault as I wasn't clear with the question at first.   But I have made some edits now, and if you re-read/understand the question and comments, it will make sense.  I tested your latest edits and it is doing the same thing/problem as mine (making other spacers have zero size)

I got what you mean by taking all the space. This new edit should fix it

Ok that is the best answer so far, but for pre ios 17 it is more of a workaround. It would be nice to see the entire space. for the ios 17 containerrelativeframe, it doesn't seem to be taking all the horizontal space, even if I set the containing vstacks' frame to infinity.

To ...make a Spacer visible for debugging in SwiftUI try this approach using GeometryReader.
The size of the Spacer view will be the same as the size of the GeometryReader view, which is the size of the available space.
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("I am a dynamic object")
            GeometryReader { geo in
                Spacer()
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
                    .background(Color.red)
            }
            Text("Me too.")
            GeometryReader { geo in
                Spacer()
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
                    .background(Color.blue)
            }
            Text("Me three")
            GeometryReader { geo in
                Spacer()
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
                    .background(Color.green)
            }
            Text("hi.")
        }
    }
}

More apparent when using MacCatalyst and changing the outer view/window size.
Note, you can also use .border(.red) instead of .background(Color.red).
EDIT-1:
more compactly:
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("I am a dynamic object")
            GeoSpacer(.red)
            Text("Me too.")
            GeoSpacer(.blue)
            Text("Me three")
            GeoSpacer() // <--- .clear
            Text("hi.")
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder func GeoSpacer(_ color: Color = .clear) -> some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            Spacer()
                .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
                .border(color)
        }
    }
}

